# android - Remote testing with Google sign in

Tags: android, android-emulator, automated-tests, android-espresso, google-signin

My app is built to use Google Play Services API and fully relies on Google sign in.
Now I've decided to add some instrumented tests into the project. I'm able to run them locally on an emulator or a real device, but I've faced a problem to do that on a remote emulator within a CI server (I'm using Travis CI).
When the app launches for the first time, user is prompted for his Google account and following screen appears.

[image]

When this happens locally I'm able to enter the password and keep tests alive, but on a remote server I can do nothing and the tests fail.

So here is my question: 
How can I add a Google account to a device (emulator) from command line/espresso code/via Travis CI tools? Is it possible to do this using adb/avd command line tools?